# jenkins: pass multiple "Extended Choice Parameter" values using a URL

Tags: jenkins

One of the parameters in my `Jenkins` build is an [Extended Choice Parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) which is submitted as a selection of comma separated values when invoking the build from the build webpage.

However, I also need to invoke the build using `wget` + `URL`.

So, in the format:

```
wget "${JENKINS_URL}/job/buildname/buildWithParameters?ECP_LIST=blah1&token=token"
```

Say my Extended Choice Parameter ECP_LIST has possible values: blah1, blah2, blah3, blah4.

if I invoke, for example:

```
wget "${JENKINS_URL}/job/buildname/buildWithParameters?ECP_LIST=blah3&token=token"
```

the build starts fine with value blah3 for the EPC_LIST parameter.

However, if I wish to invoke it with 2 or more values, it just passes a blank value to the parameter.

I've tried separating the values using various things, like spaces, encoded comma, semi-colon. I haven't had any luck finding an answer here or on Google either.

Comment: Have you tried quoting them? As in `ECP_LIST="blah1,blah2,blah3"`. And then if that fails, try urlencoding the quotes.

Comment: Good suggestion - I had tried quoting, but not with URL encoded quotes.  Unfortunately neither worked:
wget "${JENKINS_URL}/job/buildname/buildWithParameters?ECP_LIST=%22blah3%20blah4%22&token=token"

Comment: I also tried %22blah3,blah4%22

Comment: I'm running into this same problem.  Even if I urlencode it still won't take more than a single value.  What finally worked for you?

Comment: Hi @onionjake. I've added a solution below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Including the URL in single quotes work:

```
wget '${JENKINS_URL}/job/buildname/buildWithParameters?ECP_LIST=blah3&token=token'
```

Similarly if you want to run a curl through your Jenkins API with curl you would run:

```
curl -X POST 'http://api:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@jenkins.YOURSERVER.com/job/BUILDNAME/buildWithParameters?parameter2=blah&parameter2=blahblah'
```

Comment: I added a solution below

Comment: sudo curl --insecure --user $USER:$PASSWORD \
-X POST "${JOB_URL}/buildWithParameters?&param1=value&param2=value&param3=value&param4=value"

Answer (score 10):

I did solve it by selecting `ECP_LIST` multiple times:

```
wget "${JENKINS_URL}/job/buildname/buildWithParameters?ECP_LIST=blah1&ECP_LIST=blah2&ECP_LIST=blah3&token=token"
```

Will result in:

```
ECP_LIST=blah1,blah2,blah3
```

I hope that works for you.

Comment: Note, that it is cleaner to use Post-build Actions, Trigger parameterized build on other projects, and pass properties from a file; you can just do something like:

echo "ECP_LIST=blah1,blah2,blah3" > prop_file.txt

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode your URL before you pass it to wget I think, if your parameters contain special chars. I do it like this in python. I use curl.

```
url_params = {'param1' : param_value1, 'param2' : param_value2}
params_encoded = urllib.urlencode(url_params)
params = ['curl.exe', '-v', '-X', 'POST', '--show-error', '%s?%s' % (JobUrl), params_encoded]
subprocess.check_call(params)
```

Comment: Even with url encoding it still will not take more than one parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me!

```
curl -X POST -u "username:password" '${JENKINS_URL}/job/buildnamebuildWithParameters?para1=value&para2=value'
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems curl dislike multiple '&' separated parameters.
It works with `curl -X POST '${JENKINS_URL}/job/buildWithParameters' -F param1=value1 -F param2=value2`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34612575)